Is there a direct way to go from POCO to JsonNode?
I want to create a JsonNode corresponding to a C# object (a POCO).
One way to do this would be to:
string json = JsonSerializer.Serialize(poco);
JsonNode? jsonNode = JsonNode.Parse(json);

Is there a better way to do this?

A specific poco or just any poco?

What are you trying to achieve here? Not sure why you'd want to go from an object with a concrete type and definite structure to something that doesn't. Either way, did you try JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode?

@phuzi I need to manipulate the JSON DOM before doing other stuff, hence the need for JsonNode. I haven't tried SerializeToNode because the documentation makes it sound like it is only for single values, not for a whole POCO.

You can use the JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode method, which directly serializes the object to a JsonNode:
JsonNode? jsonNode = JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode(poco);

This way, you skip the overhead of serializing to a string first, making it a bit more efficient.
Edit example:
using System.Text.Json;
using System.Text.Json.Nodes;

var poco = new { Name = "John Doe", Age = 30 };
JsonNode? jsonNode = JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode(poco);
Console.WriteLine(jsonNode);

Documentation: JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode

It looks like it still serializes / deserializes under the hood, but it does use a cached buffer

Documentation makes it seem like it only works for simple values (e.g., an int, or decimal or string). Can it work for a complex/free-form POCO (multiple properties, perhaps nested objects, lists of objects etc.)?

From one of the overloads you could see that a type can be passed as a parameter, should work with other types. public static System.Text.Json.Nodes.JsonNode? SerializeToNode (object? value, Type inputType, System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions? options = default);

How about JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode
JsonNode? node = JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode(poco);


Documentation makes it seem like it only works for simple values (e.g., an int, or decimal or string). Can it work for a complex/free-form POCO (multiple properties, perhaps nested objects, lists of objects etc.)?

@markvgti Works fine.
